# How to overlay a cdf curve on a scatterplot?

Tags: r, cdf

We are trying to overlay a cdf curve on our bootstrapped scatterplot. This is our code so far and we can supply the data at your request, but when we attempt to run our lines function a flat line is drawn at the bottom. If someone could help explain how to overlay a proper curve we would greatly appreciate it.

```
num_tot <- Blind_FinalExperiment$Num
total <- sum(num_tot)
sample <- sample(num_tot, replace = TRUE)
new_sum <- sum(sample)

cdfreplication = replicate(10000, sample(num_tot, replace = TRUE))
sample_sums <- replicate(10000, sum(sample(num_tot, replace = TRUE)))
freq <- table(sample_sums)
n <- length(sample_sums)
probs <- (freq / n)
genericcdf = length(which(cdfreplication == -1))/180000
genericcdf
brandcdf = length(which(cdfreplication == 1))/180000
brandcdf

plot(probs, main = "Known Experiment")
lines(ecdf(pbinom(brandcdf,180000, (2/3))))
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're adding a cdf to a scatterplot.

Comment: In your second plot call try using `plot(..., add=TRUE)`